# Query SQL for latest records in each type

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have table like below. Where are a lot of rows, which are in different types. I want to select only newest records in each type. There are of course records with different `sensor_external_id` and `sensor_id` values.

I need to group both by `sensor_id` and `type`. And for that group (`sensor_id`, `type`) I need select rows with latest `date`.

```
id       average     date                    sensor_external_id    sensor_id    type  value
950                  2019-10-25 20:34:23     2C3AE834ED58          124          3     25
951      25          2019-10-25 20:34:23     2C3AE834ED58          124          0     25
952      56          2019-10-25 20:34:23     2C3AE834ED58          124          2     56
953      43          2019-10-25 20:34:23     2C3AE834ED58          124          1     41
1411                 2019-10-25 20:54:23     2C3AE834ED58          124          3     25
1412     24          2019-10-25 20:54:23     2C3AE834ED58          124          0     23
1413     53          2019-10-25 20:54:23     2C3AE834ED58          124          2     47
1414     41          2019-10-25 20:54:24     2C3AE834ED58          124          1     36
```

In this case I need exactly that result:

```
id       average     date                    sensor_external_id    sensor_id    type  value
1411                 2019-10-25 20:54:23     2C3AE834ED58          124          3     25
1412     24          2019-10-25 20:54:23     2C3AE834ED58          124          0     23
1413     53          2019-10-25 20:54:23     2C3AE834ED58          124          2     47
1414     41          2019-10-25 20:54:24     2C3AE834ED58          124          1     36
```

I was trying to group by `type` and `date`, but without success.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a typical greatest-n per group question. A generic solution that works across most RDBMS with usually good performance is to use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.date = (
    select max(t1.date) from mytable t1 where t1.type = t.type
)
```

For performance, you want an index on `(type, date)`.

---

If you want the latest record per `type` *and* `sensor_id`, then:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.date = (
    select max(t1.date) 
    from mytable t1 
    where t1.type = t.type and t1.sensor_id = t.sensor_id
)
```

Comment: It is not working correctly in 100%, because of different date values. So now I have got rows with newest date, but for one sensor_id latest date can be 2019-10-25 20:54:23, but for other for example 2019-10-25 21:17:08

Comment: So you want the latest record per type *and* sensor_id?

Comment: Yes. In current example there are records, where one sensor_id has 4 different rows (different types).

Comment: @Greggy: I updated my answer with a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Use row_number()

```
   Select * from(  Select *, 
      row_number() over
    (partition by type order by date desc)
    from table) rn) t where t.rn=1
```